# Meteor - Angular 2 Routing Permissions

Tags: angular2-meteor

I am trying to run through the meteor -Angular2 tutorial and I am up to section 8 on this page:

http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/user-accounts-authentication-and-permissions

Code snippet 8.9 shows:

**app.routes.ts (original to suit RC4)**

```
import { RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import { PartiesListComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-list.component';
import { PartyDetailsComponent } from './imports/parties/party-details.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: PartiesListComponent },
  { path: 'party/:partyId', component: PartyDetailsComponent, canActivate: ['CanActivateForLoggedIn'] }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  { provide: 'CanActivateForLoggedIn', useValue: () => !! Meteor.userId() }
];
```

However this is for Angular 2 RC4. I have modified my app up to this point to work with RC5. My same file looks like this:

**app.routes.ts (modified by me to suit RC5)**

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {PartiesListComponent} from './imports/parties/parties-list.component';
import {PartyDetailsComponent} from './imports/parties/party-details.component';

const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PartiesListComponent },
    { path: 'party/:partyId', component: PartyDetailsComponent, canActivate: ['CanActivateForLoggedIn'] }
];

export const APP_ROUTES = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
    { provide: 'CanActivateForLoggedIn', useValue: () => !! Meteor.userId() }
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...  
@NgModule({
        imports: [
            APP_ROUTES,
            BrowserModule,
            MeteorModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            PartiesFormComponent,
            PartiesListComponent,
            PartyDetailsComponent,
            LoginButtons
        ],
        providers: [
            FormBuilder,
            APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS   // from app.routes.ts
        ],
        bootstrap: [
            APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            AppComponent
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

However angular 2 does not like the object in the `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` and reports the following stack trace:

> metadata_resolver.js:551Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for
>   [object Object]: (?).CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:551CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:448(anonymous function) @
>   metadata_resolver.js:313CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:313RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @
>   runtime_compiler.js:150RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @
>   runtime_compiler.js:72RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @
>   runtime_compiler.js:49PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @
>   application_ref.js:368PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @
>   application_ref.js:361meteorInstall.client.main.js @
>   main.ts:12fileEvaluate @ install.js:153require @
>   install.js:82(anonymous function) @ parties.collection.ts:16

What am I doing wrong here and how can this be resolved?

Many thanks

JT

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have APP_ROUTE_PROVIDERS constant declared in **app.routes** I added

```
{ provide: 'CanActivateForLoggedIn', useValue: () => !! Meteor.userId() }
```

in the **app.module** as a `providers` under the `@NgModule` decorator. This is now my code:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        APP_ROUTES,
        BrowserModule,
        MeteorModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PartiesFormComponent,
        PartiesListComponent,
        PartyDetailsComponent,
        LoginButtons
    ],
    providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        { provide: 'CanActivateForLoggedIn', useValue: () => !! Meteor.userId() }
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

Hope this helps someone.

JT